# What are the support upgrades of each armor specialization?

Tags: halo-4

I see that when you reach rank 50 you can begin to unlock "support upgrades" via "armor specializations".  It will be a while before I get to that rank, but since I will need to make a choice I'd like to have my decision made ahead of time (instead of stopping matchmaking to do research ****gasp****).  What support upgrades are unlocked for each specialization?  Are there any prerequisites which limit which armor specialization I choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This IGN page](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Specializations) gives a list of specializations, and for each the page that it links to gives the corresponding support upgrade armor mod that you can unlock. For each specialization, the support upgrade is as follows:

- Wetwork: [Stealth](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Stealth) (Allows fast and silent movement)
- Pioneer: [Fast Track](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Fast_Track) (Increases EXP gain)
- Engineer: [Drop Recon](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Drop_Recon) (Shows you the location and time of ordinance drops before other players know)
- Tracker: [Requisition](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Requisition) (Allows you to recall ordinance requests)
- Rogue: [Stability](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Stability) (Increased aiming stability when taking fire)
- Stalker: [Nemesis](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Nemesis) (Shows the locations of enemies that previously attacked you)
- Pathfinder: [Gunner](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Gunner) (Decreases vehicle weapon overheat time and increases speed when carrying a turret)
- Operator: [Wheelman](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Wheelman) (Increases stamina and durability of vehicles that you pilot)